# Truecrypt Boot Volume - Keyfiles?

Tags: linux, windows, security, encryption, truecrypt

I am actively using keyfiles for non-boot partitions and files (containers?), but I am wanting to bring this into the full system with a boot partition containing my OS (Windows or Linux). However, I really like the security keyfiles offer against bruteforcing, and commonly employ 25 1MB files as keyfiles (essentially a 25 million character password). Right now, I leave the OS unencrypted but store all the important files in the container and this allows me to use Keyfiles.

I don't want to wipe and reboot if I don't have the option, and the docs fail to explicitly say whether it be available or not.

Anyone tried?

Comment: 25.1MB key files are ridiculously big. 256-512 bits of key is plenty for AES (likely the only cypher you should be using). Truecrypt includes a function for generating such a file (do not use a plain ASCII/text file).

Comment: To clarify, it is 25 x 1MB key files, plus a 15+ character password. I've been doing a lot of testing recently, and since I am on a Retina Mac (with all the upgrades), the encryption is nearly instantaneous. I am using a compound encryption, with one of them being AES. But the reasoning aside, is there any option to do such a thing with Truecrypt boot partitions?

Comment: I think you have no idea how encryption works.

Comment: I feel I have a good understanding, but I'd be happy to read any links you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Follow the built-in Wizard for "Encrypt System Partition/Drive" under System.

Comment: Awesome. And I will have the ability to use keyfiles?

Comment: The keyfile would have to be on an unencrypted volume somewhere (usually a USB stick). It couldn't be on the encrypted boot volume.